# shifted set of residue classes hitting intervals of length p/k Alon and Spencer problem 4.8.6

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory

I am working on the problem 4.8.6 from Alon and Spencer and I am completely stuck. The problem is the following:

We have a set $X$ of at least $4k^2$ residue classes modulo a prime $p$. We want to show that there is an integer $a$ such that the set $\{xa (mod p): x\in X \}$ intersects every interval of length at least $p/k$.

What I've figured out so far is that looking at random variable $ax$ for random $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ is problematic as those variables are not independent for $x\in X$ so I should be looking at $ax +b$ (obviously modulo $p$) where we choose $a$ and $b$ uniformly and at random. Now my idea is to count the expected number of intervals intersected by such variables use the Markovs or Chebyshevs inequality but I don't know how to do it or if it is even the right idea.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the random mapping $ax+b$ where the coefficients
$a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ are chosen uniformly and thus the quantity $ax+b$ is itself uniform in $\mathbb{Z}_p.$

Let $I$ be an arbitrary interval of length $v=\lceil p/k\rceil$. Fix an $x\in X.$ Then the probability that some $z \in I$ is hit by the random variable above is $1/p$ thus the probability that no $z \in I$ is hit is (by independence)
$$
P_{fail}=\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{v}\leq \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{p/k}.
$$
Now consider the set of random variables $\{ax+b:x\in X\},$ giving
$$
P_{fail}=\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{v\cdot 4k^2}\leq \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{4pk} \sim \exp(-4k),
$$
ensuring this probability is very small across the whole range of possible $k\geq 1.$

Comment: Hi, this doesn't exactly  answer my question as I small probability of failure doesn't guarantee a success. I am pretty sure that we need to use expectations and variations here